# Errors compiling a program

Tags: c++

I'm compiling an open source project but I'm getting an error I've never seen before:

```
luascript.cpp: In member function ‘bool LuaInterface::loadDirectory(const string&, Npc*, bool)’:
luascript.cpp:742:41: error: ‘boost::filesystem2::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem2::path_traits>::string_type’ has no member named ‘string’
```

and this is the source code:

```
bool LuaInterface::loadDirectory(const std::string& dir, Npc* npc/* = NULL*/, bool recursively/* = false*/)
{
StringVec files;
for(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator it(dir), end; it != end; ++it)
{
    std::string s = it->path().filename().string(); //This is line 742
    if(boost::filesystem::is_directory(it->status()))
    {
        if(recursively && !loadDirectory(it->path().filename() + "/" + s, npc, recursively))
            return false;
    }
    else if((s.size() > 4 ? s.substr(s.size() - 4) : "") == ".lua")
        files.push_back(s);
}

std::sort(files.begin(), files.end());
for(StringVec::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); ++it)
{
    if(!loadFile(dir + (*it), npc))
        return false;
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: quick-glance here, but it seems your using "string" before you create it. basically  - this is a simple error

Comment: @Coffee Do you have any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Comment: Belongs on helpdesk.stackexchange.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older versions of boost filesystem the return type of the method filename() is of string_type and not of type path. string_type does not have the member filename() contrary to the path type.

For the older version of boost you are using you can just remove the .string() part in the code.